# iOS UIWebView - trap exceptions

Tags: ios, exception, uiwebview

I have a same question that was disscussed in this post"iOS UIWebView - trap exceptions loading invalid file format", but no solution there.
Can anybody give me any suggestion? I have been stucked in the question for a whole day.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tested :

```
@try {
    <#statements#>
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    <#handler#>
}
@finally {
    <#statements#>
}
```